# looping through directories with functions in R

Tags: r, csv

I have 3 CSV files on my desktop in a folder called letter_xyx
created by putting the following data frames into csv files

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
b <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
c <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
```

I have created a simple function called mult that simply creates a new column in the data frame with the sum of the first column.

```
mult <- function(df){
df %>% mutate(sum(X1))
}
```

I would like to write a for loop that goes through the folder letter_xyz, performs the function on each file in the folder, and return each file as a new csv file in a new folder.

I am not quite sure how to do this,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `for` loop and file IO functions,

```
## Your function
mult <- function(df) df %>% mutate(sum(X1))

dir.create("output")                                   # create output folder 
for (file in list.files("data", full.names = T)) {     # loop through files in "data" folder
    dat <- mult(read.csv(file))                        # read file and apply function
    fname <- gsub(".*/([A-Za-z]+\\.csv)", "\\1", file)   # make output filename
    write.csv(dat, sprintf("output/%s", fname))        # write file
}
```